# TableView with detailed view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, mmdrawercontroller

I little confused with configuring detailed view with MMDrawerController and without navigation controller.

I have TableView with custom cells inside ViewController. When users presses cell i want to show another ViewController with details about selected item. For this case i use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method from my tableview.

There are many cells in my table, that is why when user presses "back" button on detailed view i want to navigate to selected cell not to the top of table. What types of segues i should use?

Comment: i think on viewWillAppear r u refreshed the table , just hidden that

Comment: i don't use viewWillAppear but i use MMDrawerController to show ViewController with table view.